# How to SUM the total value of a column and add it at the end of table?

Tags: java

Hwllo, I am trying to sum up the value of a column in jTable and add it at the end of table.
e.g: I want to sum the values of unit_price column...

Anyone can help me please?

The way I coded:

```
 ...

    Statement st= 
    con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= 
    st.executeQuery("SELECT id, 
    item_name, unit_price From item");
    rs.last();

    int row= rs.getRow();
    int column= 
    rs.getMetaData.getColumnCount();
    String[][] data= new String[row]. 
    [column];
    rs.beforeFirst();
    int x=0;
    while(rs.next){
    for(int i=0; i<column; i++){
    data[x][i]=rs.getString(i+1);
    }
     x++;
     }
    String columns=. 
      {"Id","Item_name","Unit_price"};
    jTable1 = new 
    javax.swing.JTable(data, columns);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

Comment: Instead of a 2d String array you should have an array of a custom class containing the data from a row in the item table. It will be much easier to do further work with your data this way.

Comment: Could you explain more please?

Comment: Create a class with a member variable for each column you returning in your sql and create a new instance and set the variables for each row in your result set. Once you have that it should be easier to accomplish want you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the next query instead of `SELECT id, item_name, unit_price From item`:

```sql
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN id IS NULL
            THEN 'TOTAL'
            ELSE MAX(item_name) 
            END item_name, 
       SUM(unit_price) unit_price 
FROM item
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP;
```

I assume that `id` is table's PRIMARY KEY.

If you need in some specific sorting order then the `ORDER BY` clause must look like

```
ORDER BY id IS NOT NULL, {needed sorting expression}
```

Comment: Sorry. How to handle the java part? not the query itself.

Comment: @Hadi Why you tag the question as MySQL-related when you need the solution for Java side only? Adjust.